# Twilio - Save SMS body, sid and sender in Ruby

Tags: ruby, twilio

I have followed the guide [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ySKBUVsuf8) to set up a sinatra app that successfully receives and responds to a text sent to my Twilio account.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twilio-ruby'

post '/receive_sms' do
    content_type 'text/xml'
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Message 'Message recieved'
    end
    response.to_xml
end
```

How can I retrieve the SMS body, sender, and SID of the message and store them as a variable? Ex: `body = "Test message"`

I have tried adding `response.text` to return the xml response and possibly parse the output but did not have any luck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The message parameters are sent as form encoded parameters, which luckily Sinatra already reads for you. You can get the body, sender and SID like so:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twilio-ruby'

post '/receive_sms' do
    body   = params["Body"]
    sid    = params["MessageSid"]
    sender = params["From"]
    content_type 'text/xml'
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Message 'Message recieved'
    end
    response.to_xml
end
```

You can see all [the parameters available in Twilio's request in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters).

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!